# Different ciphertexts when I used OpenSSL AES command line tools and OpenSSL AES APIs?

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, aes, javax.crypto

Why do i got different ciphertexts when i used openssl aes command tools and openssl AES apis ?

I have used three types of encryption:

- Type a) openssl command line tool
- Type b) classes in javax.cryto
- Type c) OpenSSL C api.

Using type (a) and (b), I got the same ciphertext. But I got different ciphertext when using (c).

I want to get the same ciphertexts when using method c and method a/b.
I think there's something wrong in type c, but I can't find it. Note that I used the same KEY,IV pair in the above three methods.

***Type a***:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -e -a -in pt.txt -out ct.txt -K 01010101010101010101010101010101 -iv 01010101010101010101010101010101 -p
```

***Type b***:
Java code using javax.crypto. I won't paste the code, because this way I got the same ciphertext with Type a.

***Type c***:
C code using OpenSSL API:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    AES_KEY aes;
    unsigned char key[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];        // AES_BLOCK_SIZE = 16
    unsigned char iv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];        // init vector
    unsigned char* input_string;
    unsigned char* encrypt_string;
    unsigned char* decrypt_string;
    unsigned int len;        // encrypt length (in multiple of AES_BLOCK_SIZE)
    unsigned int i;

    // check usage
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s <plain text>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }

    // set the encryption length
    len = 0;
    if ( strlen(argv[1])>=AES_BLOCK_SIZE || 
         (strlen(argv[1]) + 1) % AES_BLOCK_SIZE == 0) {
        len = strlen(argv[1]) + 1;
    } else {
        len = ((strlen(argv[1]) + 1) / AES_BLOCK_SIZE + 1) * AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
    }

    // set the input string
    input_string = (unsigned char*)calloc(len, sizeof(unsigned char));
    if (input_string == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory for input_string\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    strncpy((char*)input_string, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));

    // Generate AES 128-bit key
    memset(key, 0x01, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);

    // Set encryption key
    memset(iv, 0x01, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
    if (AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, &aes) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to set encryption key in AES\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // alloc encrypt_string
    encrypt_string = (unsigned char*)calloc(len, sizeof(unsigned char));    
    if (encrypt_string == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory for encrypt_string\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // encrypt (iv will change)
    AES_cbc_encrypt(input_string, encrypt_string, len, &aes, iv, AES_ENCRYPT);

    /////////////////////////////////////

    // alloc decrypt_string
    decrypt_string = (unsigned char*)calloc(len, sizeof(unsigned char));
    if (decrypt_string == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory for decrypt_string\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // Set decryption key
    memset(iv, 0x01, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
    if (AES_set_decrypt_key(key, 128, &aes) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to set decryption key in AES\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // decrypt
    AES_cbc_encrypt(encrypt_string, decrypt_string, len, &aes, iv, 
            AES_DECRYPT);

    // print
    printf("input_string =%s\n", input_string);
    printf("encrypted string =");
    for (i=0; i<len; ++i) {
        printf("%u ", encrypt_string[i]);    
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("decrypted string =%s\n", decrypt_string);

    return 0;
}
```

What could be the reason for different outputs?

Comment: What are the inputs and different outputs? Do they differ totally, or only in the last block?

Comment: I couldn't past my result here,bcz this website complained the format!   So i past the result in another website, please see http://topic.csdn.net/u/20120207/16/48183c46-8afd-47d9-a260-7a5eb571f877.html?seed=661539550&r=77510138#r_77510138                          A chinese deveplop bbs,please see Groupd Four . Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your C code, you are essentially using **zero-padding**: You allocate a memory area filled by zeros (by [`calloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/calloc/)), and then copy the plain text into this area, leaving the zeros at the end intact.

The `openssl enc` uses different padding than your C code. The [documentation for `openssl enc`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/enc.html) says (emphasis by me):

> All the block ciphers normally use **PKCS#5 padding** also known as standard
>   block padding: this allows a rudimentary integrity or password check to be performed.
>   However since the chance of random data passing the test is better than 1 in 256 it
>   isn't a very good test.

In addition, the `openssl enc` command uses a salt by default, which randomizes the ciphertext. The salt serves a similar purpose as a per-message Initialization Vector (IV). But you are using an explicit IV, so the salt is *not* randomizing the ciphertext.

The [documentation for javax.crypto.Cipher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?javax/crypto/Cipher.html) (which I suppose you used) says:

> A transformation is of the form:
>
> - *"algorithm/mode/padding"* or
> - *"algorithm"*
>
> (in the latter case, **provider-specific default values for the** mode and **padding
>   scheme** are used). For example, the following is a valid transformation:
>
> ```
> Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
> ```

So if you simply are using `AES` or `ARS/CBC` without indicating the padding mode, it uses whatever it finds fitting, which in your case happened to be the same as what OpenSSL used (i.e. PKCS#5 padding).

To change your C program, you'll have to do the same padding yourself (essentially, it is filling the block with a number x of bytes, all of which have the same value as this number, while appending a whole block filled with 16 when the last block is already full) - or use the higher level EVP-functions, which should provide you with a way to specify the padding mode to the cipher.

Comment: Paulo Ebermann, you are exactly correct!  IT IS the padding problem!  I have made that stupid mistake! I'll paste the result in the website http://topic.csdn.net/u/20120207/16/48183c46-8afd-47d9-a260-7a5eb571f877.html   . I appreciate your help very much. I'd to make friends with u.  My email is dungeonsnd#126.com or dungeonsnd#gmail.com  . Thanks again.

Comment: If my answer helped you to find the solution, feel free to mark it as *accepted* by clicking the big check mark icon beside it. This is the *build in* way of saying "thanks" on this website.